# Xamarin Forms Proyectoi Portable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Buenas tardes, tengo instalado Xamarin con Visual Studio 2017 en Windows 7. Estoy intentando crear un proyecto nuevo, pero no tengo la opciòn de PORTABLE, me aparece Cross-Platform Xamarin Forms pero no me crea el proyecto en común, me crea el de Android y el de IOS pero no el común a ambos.

Que podrá estar sucediendo? y porque no encuentro la opción Portable?

GRACIAS

Comment: cuando estás creando el proyecto, te aparece una ventana donde puedes elegir las plataformas para tu proyecto Cross platform? Si te aparece una opción que se refiere a UWP o Windows 10, desmárcala y prueba otra vez. Los proyectos de UWP no se pueden crear o abrir en Windows 7 y quizás por ahí esté el problema.

Answer (score 3):

Gracias a las ultimas versiones de Xamarin y Visual Studio, Portable Classes ya no esta soportado. En su lugar solo veras Shared Proyects y .NET Standard 2.0 libraries que son los que se estan usando ahorita , ya no mas PCL.